# Нужна помощь в том, что бы перевести sql запрос из Mysql диалекта в postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD FULLTEXT INDEX IndexName (ColumnName)
```

Помогите перевести это в postgres диалект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тема полнотекстового поиска куда более объёмна нежели создание одного индекса. Но в первом приближении примерно аналогичный запрос будет выглядеть как:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index_name ON TableName USING gist
  (to_tsvector('english', ColumnName))
```

- [`CREATE INDEX`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html) — создание индекса.
- `USING` [`gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gist-intro.html) — задаёт движок индекса типа «обобщённое деререво поиска», также можно использовать [`gin`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin-intro.html), конкретный выбор зависит от деталей.
- `to_tsvector('english', ColumnName)` — конвертирует текст в поисковый вектор по которому и строится поиск, где `english` — имя конфигурации поиска для английского языка; из коробки в числе прочего идёт конфиг для русского (`'russion'`), полный список доступен по команде `\dF` `psql`'я.

Дальнейшее чтение:

- Неплохая [обзорная статья из гугла](https://eax.me/postgresql-full-text-search/) по полнотекстовому поиску.